# Simplify code for a < sign in Metafont

Tags: fonts, math-fonts, metafont

As I am a beginner in Metafont, I am still not sure if my code is efficient. I would like to replace the Computer Modern's less than sign by a new one, which has rounded corners.

I found 2 ways:

The first example is based on 2 strokes. Disadvantage: An overlap (can be removed in Fontforge, but removing results in 2 unnecessary points).

```
% ... Rest as in sym.mf
compute_spread(5/4x_height#,3/2x_height#);
beginchar(less,14u#,v_center(spread#+rule_thickness#));
italcorr h#*slant-u#;
pickup fine.nib;
pos1(rth,90); pos2(rth,90); pos3(rth,90);
lft x2l=hround 1.5u; x1=x3=w-x2;
y1-y3=spread; y2=.5[y1,y3]=math_axis;
filldraw stroke z1e--z2e;
filldraw stroke z2e--z3e;
penlabels(1,2,3); endchar;
% ...
```

2nd example: based on filldraw. No overlap, but more complicated. (-> Picture)

```
% ... Rest as in sym.mf
compute_spread(5/4x_height#,3/2x_height#);
beginchar(less,14u#,v_center(spread#+rule_thickness#));
italcorr h#*slant-u#;
pickup fine.nib;
pos1(rth,90); pos2(rth,90); pos3(rth,90);
lft x2l=hround 1.5u; x1=x3=w-x2;
y1-y3=spread; y2=.5[y1,y3]=math_axis;
y4=y2; z4=whatever[z2r,z3r];
filldraw z1r--z2r--z2l--z3l--z3r--z4--z1l--cycle;
penlabels(1,2,3); endchar;
```

I am not sure. That does not look as professional as the Computer Modern sources. Is there a way to simplify and shorten the code?

[image]

Edit: Missing code line in both cases: `rth:=rule_thickness;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution for an even nicer less sign with better code:

```
rth := rule_thickness;
compute_spread(5/4x_height#,3/2x_height#);
beginchar(253,32u#,v_center(spread#+rule_thickness#));
italcorr h#*slant-u#;
pickup fine.nib;
pos1(rth,-90); pos2(whatever,0); pos3(rth,90);
lft x2l=hround 1.5u; x1=x3=w-x2l;
y1-y3=spread; y2=.5[y1,y3]=math_axis;
z2r=z3r+whatever*(z2l-z3l);
filldraw stroke z1e--z2e--z3e;
penlabels(1,2,3); endchar;
```

[image]